# TypeScript: Property 'mockImplementation' does not exist on type in Jest Test

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have this basically:

```
// Example.ts

class Example {
  returnSomething() {
    return false
  }
}

export default new Example()
```

Then in a TypeScript Jest test I have this:

```
// Example/__tests__/index.test.ts

jest.mock('Example', () => ({
  _esModule: true,
  returnSomething: jest.fn(() => true)
  isFeatureEnabled: jest.fn(),
}))

// then down below:
it('some test', () => {
  Example.returnSomething.mockImplementation(() => 'foo')
})
```

But I am getting that error:

```
Property 'mockImplementation' does not exist on type ...
```

How do I get the jest wrapped mock of the function to work properly in TypeScript for this test?

Is there anything better than this?

```
(Example.returnSomething as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(() => 'foo')
```

Comment: See https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/blob/master/docs/user/test-helpers.md#mocked

Comment: link does not work anymore

Comment: hey alien, have you found a workaround for this?